# Relocation error with gcc when using extern

Tags: c++

I am getting a relocation error for the following piece of code. Please could someone help me figure out the issue.

A.hpp

```
namespace
{
class A
{
    public:
        A(const std::string&);
        //Few Get() methods
    private:
        //Some private stuff
};
    extern A objA;
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include<A.hpp>

const std::string str("FIXED STRING HERE");
A objA(str);

A::A(const std::string& Istring)
{
    //Some data processing here
}
```

**ClientCode.cpp**

```
#include<A.hpp>



// Want to access A::get() here using objA;
objA.Get();
```

I get the following error:

> relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `(anonymous namespace)::str' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Additionally please could someone tell when does the memory for this extern object get allocated.
My main intention is to have only single object of class A and use it across many files whenever i include A.hpp

Answer (score 1):

A.hpp

```
namespace ABC
{
    class A
    {
        public:
            A(const std::string&);
            //Few Get() methods
        private:
            //Some private stuff
    };
  extern A objA;
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include<A.hpp>
namespace ABC
{
     const std::string str("FIXED STRING HERE");
      A objA(str);

      A::A(const std::string& Istring)
      {
         //Some data processing here
      }
}
```

ClientCode.cpp

```
#include<A.hpp>
// Want to access A::get() here using objA;
ABC::objA.Get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `extern` to explicitly declare the `str` and `objA` in `ClientCode.cpp` as to- be-linked symbol defined from other object file compiled from other cpp source file.

```
#include<A.hpp>

extern const std::string str;
extern A objA;

// Want to access A::get() here using objA;
objA.Get();
```

============
**EDIT**

Also erase the `extern` statement in `A.hpp`

```
namespace
{
class A
{
    public:
        A(const std::string&);
        //Few Get() methods
    private:
        //Some private stuff
};
    //extern A objA;
}
```

Comment: U mean i let the code inside A.cpp as is? 

const std::string str("FIXED STRING HERE");
A objA(str);

Comment: @user3836455 yes. The global class initialization would take place before `main()` entry execution.

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't working.. Error returned "error: reference to 'objA' is ambiguous"

Comment: @user3836455 `objA.Get();` should be in a function not global.

Comment: Yes, its not global, it is inside a function

Comment: @user3836455 And check how you link A.o compiled from A.cpp to your executable.

Comment: @user3836455 update with erasing the redundant `extern` statement in `A.hpp`

Comment: @user3836455 I've tried on my mac and well compiled, so please confirm that on yours :)

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn't seem to work for me. Getting the same relocation error.

Comment: @user3836455 Have not erased the `extern A objA;` statement in `A.hpp`? Surely you get ambiguous error when this statement be put in header file.

Comment: I have erased the extern A objA from A.hpp file, but now i am getting the relocation error for the Constructor A::A(const std::string&)

Comment: use any IDE? Just link A.cpp compiled object file A.o to your intended executable!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, it was due to namespace. Many Thanks for your guidance and lot of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The relocation error is probably due to the "anonymous" namespace.. you have to assign a name to the namespace.

As far as concern about when memory get allocated for the external object identificator, it is when you Call the object constructor. The declaration of an object identificator as  external has the effect to indicate to the compiler that identificator can be used among several  files and so when linking, all the files that contain that identificator, point to the same object.

Obviously the instantiation (when and where) depends by the programmer, who has responsibility to do it correctly in order to avoid object not instantiated error, a sort of null reference error.